# How is Music player meant to be closed?

Tags: music

By default the Music player (`noise`) keeps playing if closed, as it has this option enabled by default.

[image]

So closing means closing the GUI and losing access to its graphical options.

What can the purpose of this be and how it is supposed to be closed in this case?

Comment: please commend when down-voting to give a hint on what is wrong here so that i can fix it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, Music doesn't stop playing just because the window is closed. Very seldom will one actually want or need the window while Music is playing. In this way, Music is a bit of a service. There is an app that allows you fine grained control or you can control playback from the indicator or very passively from media keys, but the window is not required to be open taking up space and cluttering your workflow for you to have music playing or control its playback.

If you want to stop playback, you can use the "pause" button. **Closing the app while no music is playing will quit the app.**

Comment: This answers the question: **pause Music and then close the window**. Unless the default option is changed from settings, this is the only way to do it. - The rest of the answer is just a matter of personal preference (that should not be imposed on others: why not have the music list under my eyes when listening?)

Comment: On the other hand: closing the window may be great at times, but is there a way to show the window back after closing it?

Comment: @cipricus You can reopen the window just like you normally would any other way, from the dock, the applications menu, by clicking the album artwork in the indicator, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Well... You can flip that setting off. Or when it's on, you just stop it from the music/sound indicator on the top bar. That should work in theory and that's what I do but maybe someone else has a better idea.